# Grep in Ruby: recursive call could loop indefinitely

Tags: ruby, regex, grep

I asked [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225851/match-regular-expression-between-delimiters) to get correct grep command for certain pattern, described on the site. Now I am trying to process text file - I use modified pattern grep on each line, and if grep returns match, I want to take some actions. My code looks more or less like this:

```
file.each_line do |line|
  myVariable = `echo '#{line}' | grep -P '>(?!((?:[^)]|\((?1)\))*)$)'`
  if myVariable == '' doSomething else doOtherThing end
end
```

Each call to echo-grep line, shows this:

```
grep: recursive call could loop indefinitely
```

and returns an empty string - which indicates an error.

Now I am also running similar line:

```
myVariable = `echo "#{line}" | grep -P '>(?!((?:[^]]|\[(?1)\])*)$)'`
```

but this line works fine.

Now I get this message for every line of input, but this line is sure to give error output:

```
example <something>
```

Note that running the same comand in command line, either with echo or on file, works just fine.

Given all the information, the question is:

**What should I do to eliminate error message, and make this grep call work?**

Comment: Please use snake_case for variables. CammelCase is only for class or modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that in Ruby, you need to escape `\` character with another `\`. So, incorporating [vks's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32521958/2373609) , we get:

```
myVariable = `echo "#{line}" | grep -P '<[^>]*>(?=[^\\[]*\\])'`
myVariable = `echo "#{line}" | grep -P '<[^>]*>(?=[^\\(]*\\))'`
```

which works for [] or () respectively.

Answer (score 1):

```
<[^>]*>(?=[^\[]*\])
```

You can simply use this .See demo..

https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/9

Comment: Plus, after editing to `grep -P '<[^>]*>(?=[^\(]*\))'`, I'm getting "grep: unmatched parentheses"